# Alter table to add unique index based on combination with where clause-SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with following columns

```
   ID         int               IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   Default    bit               NOT NULL,
   [Status]   varchar (20)      --possible values 'Open','Deleted'& 'Suspended'
```

I need a alter table script to restrict only one row which is having Status = 'Open' and Default = 1

I tried this,

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE1]
ADD UNIQUE INDEX UK_TABLE1 
ON TABLE1(Default,[Status])
WHERE [Default]= 1 AND [Status] = 'Open'
```

Its not working,and gettting below exception

```
Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.
```

can anyone help on this.ALSO IS IT POSSIBLE SAME USING A TRIGGER ??

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: @Felix Pamittan .. question updated..mentioned exception also

Answer (score 2):

You should use create instead of alter:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_TABLE1 
ON TABLE1([Default],[Status])
WHERE [Default]= 1 AND [Status] = 'Open'
```

Comment: I tried..getting error..Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.

Comment: Can you say version of MS SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6241.0 (X64)   Apr 17 2015 10:56:08   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: ) (VM)

Comment: I use same version of MS SQL Server and same script and it's works.

Comment: You need drop and create index, alter table don't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table Table1 (
  ID         int               IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [Default]    bit               NOT NULL,
   [Status]   varchar (20)      )


--ALTER TABLE [TABLE1]
create UNIQUE INDEX UK_TABLE1 
ON Table1([Default],[Status])
WHERE [Default]= 1 AND [Status] = 'Open'
```

just remove alter table and replace add with create

Comment: why you want to alter table, when you are creating new index??

Comment: i have already created this table without unique index.So i want to add thins new unique index

Answer (score 0):

```
create unique index UK_TABLE1 
ON TABLE1(default,status)
WHERE default= 1 AND status = 'Open'
```